# SuperSpeed signal Routing on PCB

Tags: pcb-design, usb, altium

I'm working on a PCB Design with SuperSpeed signal lines with an Texas Instruments USB 3.0 Controller. I´m new on PCB design and I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

[image]

Can I cross the USB DM/DP lines?

Are the ssrx/sstx routed ok? I´m putting ground planes between SSRX+ and SSRX- (the same for TX lines) and matching the length. Do I have to put more ground planes between SSRX and SSTX lines?

Another question, Is there any problem with vias on pads?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, you can't swap DM and DP, it won't work.
2. SuperSpeed pairs are not routed OK. The wires of a pair are not equal length, it could be better. Typically there would be no ground between wires of a pair.
3. You can have ground between two pairs if there is enough distance but not really between two wires of a pair.
4. There are unequal amount of vias, one wire of a pair has 4 more vias than the other.

I suggest reading more about routing high speed signals, there should be guides from USB chip manufacturers how to route them, so check the material that your manufacturer provides for your chip.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I don't want swap DM and DP, I asked if DM can pass over DN.

I didn't understand well the manual, I have fixed the ground planes, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: About length measures, on the document I'm reading, it says about "Internal Chip Trace Length Mismatch", I have to keep on mind this when I measure the wires, right? The chip document doesn't say nothing about number of vias, is an standar rule?

Thank you so much.